# What Lego set does this bag belong to

Tags: set-identification

Not sure what Lego set this bag is from can anyone help.

Comment: Hi Tina! We'd gladly help, but your question lacks any details or photos. Please edit to add more information and we'll do our best. Welcome to Bricks.SE :)